# What are the digits that make this equation true in this cryptarithm?

Tags: puzzle, cryptography

**Can you find digits that make the equations true in the following alphametic puzzle (cryptarithm)?**

$$RE + MI = FA$$
$$DO + SI = MI$$
$$LA + SI = SOL$$

- Zero may be a possible variable
- No one digit may be represented by more than one variable

Comment: Can we assume no leading 0's and no digit being represented by more than one letter?

Comment: Safe to assume leading 0's, but no one digit can be represented by more than one letter.

Comment: The usual rules for these are no leading zeros and all letters represent distinct digits.

Comment: Well even if it was a rule that it could be used, I don't think it is possible to have 0 as one of them anyways.

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation you have $O=0$. Also, since $SOL$ is the sum of two digit numbers, it follows that $S=1$.

Thus, so far we have

$$RE+MI=FA$$
$$D0+1I=MI$$
$$LA+1I=10L$$

From the last equation we get $L=8$ or $L=9$. Also, we know $D+1=M$ from the second.

Now, if each letter is a different digit, combining $E+I=A$ or $E+I=1A$ from the first equation with $A+I=L$ and $L \in \{ 8, 9 \}$, and studying the four possible cases should lead to the solution.

Comment: How do you know O = 0?

Comment: Look at the last digit of $DO+SI=MI$.

Comment: @AaronWalker:  We know $O=0$ from the ones digit of the second equation, which says $O+I=I$ (possibly, though not in this case, with a carry).  This is one of the first things to look at when solving  cryptarithms.